# React useState, value of input doesnt update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I wish to generate inputs based on json, so first I set it to initial state, then in child componenet I want to modify it's field, thing is that component doesnt update... It renders once and have no idea how to make it be updated each time when input onChange change it's value. Any idea how to make value of input be updated each time when I type something?

PARENT

```
 function App() {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(chunkingRow);


  const handleChunkingChange = (e, index) => {
    let inputContent = inputValue;
    const reg = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);

    if (e.target.value.match(reg)) {
      inputContent[index] = {
        ...inputContent[index],
        content: e.target.value,
      };

      setInputValue(inputContent);
      console.log(inputValue);
    } else console.log('not a number')
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        {Chunk(inputValue, handleChunkingChange)}
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CHILD

```
const Chunk = (inputValue, handleChunkingChange) => {

return(
  <div>
    {inputValue.map((el, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>{el.title}</p>
        {console.log(el.content)}
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e, i) => handleChunkingChange(e, index)}
          value={el.content}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
}
```

link to demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mirzakhani-46exz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: have you tried rendering your Chunk as a React component? `<Chunk inputValue={inputValue} handleChunkingChange={handleChunkingChange} />`

Comment: The code you provide seems normal, could you provide an online demo for the explanation?

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez I tried it but no effect

Comment: @keikai I added demo link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely sure why this happens, but probably because of the way you handle the input change. It seems to me that component doesn't recognize that array changed. How I managed to fix your code is replacing line 9 in App component with following code:

```
let inputContent = [...inputValue];
```

By doing that, array's reference is changed and components are updated.

Comment: It's because the author was mutating the state and both objects were referencing the same. check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your code as follow:

```
let inputContent = [ ...inputValue ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the state object.

```
let inputContent = inputValue;
```

That's why the state is not re-rendered. Change it to

```
 let inputContent = [...inputValue];
```

An example of mutating objects. React compares previous state and current state and renders only if they are different.

```
const source = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const target = source;
console.log(target);
console.log(target === source); =  true
target.b = 99;
console.log({target});
console.log({source}); //source == target due to mutation
console.log(source === target); = true
```

Remember, never mutate.